# Cleaning dark stone kitchen countertops

Tags: cleaning

I have lived in two kitchens where the countertop was a dark stone material. In one case, it was black granite with copper flecks and in my current kitchen, it is solid dark brown quartz composite. In both places, I have noticed that simply wiping the countertop with a damp sponge or dishcloth leaves it streaky and unsightly. Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Run a clean plastic mesh covered sponge (we call them "dobies") under hot water and then squeeze out excess water so it is wet, but not dripping. Apply a few drops of dish soap to the sponge. Using a circular motion, wipe the counter surface to be cleaned, creating a light coating of thin suds on the entire counter. Take a dry dishtowel and remove the suds with long, even strokes that go from one edge to the other, pausing to refold the dishtowel so that a dry portion is always in contact with the counter, which will remove the suds effectively. Use a damp dishtowel to go over the surface again to remove any remaining soap. The counter will be shiny and streak free.